# Asp.Net MVC 5, View not posting back to the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am creating a simple login form using Asp.Net MVC 5. Everything is fine but when I click on submit button after giving User Id and Password, the view does not go back to the desired Controller Action (LogIn). Here is the Action:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogIn(User user)
        {
            var auth_user = CheckAuthentication(user);
            if(auth_user!=null)
            {
                Session["user"] = new User() { UserId = user.UserId, Name = user.Name };
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
            }
            return View();
        }
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult LogIn()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

and the view:

```
@model FinancialManagement.Models.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "LogIn";
}

<h2>LogIn</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("LogIn", "User", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>User</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserId)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

This is my complete User controller:

```
    [Authorize]
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private FinancialManagmentEntities db = new FinancialManagmentEntities();

        // GET: /User/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Users.ToList());
        }

        // GET: /User/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(user);
        }

        // GET: /User/Create
        [AllowAnonymous]

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: /User/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(User user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Users.Add(user);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(user);
        }
        ActionResult LogOut()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        User CheckAuthentication(User user)
        {
            return db.Users.Where(u => u.UserId == user.UserId && u.Password == user.Password).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult LogIn(User user)
        {
            var auth_user = CheckAuthentication(user);
            if(auth_user!=null)
            {
                Session["user"] = new User() { UserId = user.UserId, Name = user.Name };
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
            }
            return View();
        }
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult LogIn()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(user);
        }
        // POST: /User/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="UserId,Name,Password")] User user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(user);
        }
        // GET: /User/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(user);
        }

        // POST: /User/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string id)
        {
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            db.Users.Remove(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your controller name? You told "does not go back to the desired Controller Action", you mean is it going to some other controller/action and what exactly happening after clicking submit? Is it staying on same page? Also check if you have client errors in browser console.

Comment: Controller name is 'User', the same from where the view is called

Comment: After clicking on submit, same view renders again, but the textboxes are reset

Comment: Then did you check with a break point in action to see if the user is found or not? From the code you posted, if the user not found the same view will render refreshed. So when user not found, pass back `user` model you received to view.

Comment: I marked a break point on action but I noticed that control doesn't goes to it

Comment: Then cross check if on click of submit button is your page really reloading. Because the break point is not hitting the action means either your page should not reload or submit is submitting to some other controller/action which is sending back empty page. Which one do you think is correct? Also check in browser developer tools(Fibrebug) in the network tab/console and see if the request is going or not.

Comment: Are your Types correct in your View you have 'FinancialManagement.Models.User' is I am guessing the User in your controller is Identity User type

Comment: @SivaGopal I have checked all in debug mode, the control is not going to any controller but goes to dispose method of User controller at the end. Then the page shows. I try to track in it browser

Comment: What do you mean _not go back to the LogIn_? Why would you want to go back to the login page after you have already logged in? Assuming `auth_user` is not `null` your redirecting to the `Index()` method. If that method is marked with the `[Authorize]` attribute and the user is not authorized, you will be redirected back to the `Login()` method again (no where in you code you appear to be adding the authentication cookie necessary for authentication, just adding someting to `Session`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I dont want to go back to LogIn page. I was saying that when I press submit on LogIn view after giving Id and Password, it does not submit the user to Post LogIn Action. That is why control does not reaches auth_user statement or any else. On the other hand as you said of cookie, I am not familiar with cookies. Will be glad to get help about cookies from you.

Comment: Are you saying it never hits the POST method? You do not have the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute on it! (and you should also include `[ValidateAntForgeryToken]`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke! yes it never hits the POST method. I added the attributes you told but in vain. :(

Comment: If you have added `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute it should hit the POST method (although it will probably immediately redirect back to the `LogIn()` again because nothing in your code appears to authorize the user).

Comment: It doesn't. I have posted the complete controller. Kindly have a look at it and tell me of any problem with the code

Comment: The code you have shown **will** hit the `Login()` post method when you submit the form. But it will never go to the `Index()` method (or any other method marked with `[Authorize]` because the code in the `LogIn()` method does not authorize the user. And storing passwords in plain text is dreadful practice!

Answer (score -2):

Try to specify the View's Name and your Model like that :

```
return View("NameOfView", YourModel);
```

If it doesn't work put the absolute path :

```
return View("~/Views/FolderName/ViewName.cshtml");
```

Comment: Problem is returning back from view to controller. Not going to view from the controller